# How to consolidate many case statements Postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

EDITED QUESTION:

I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (id INT, type_key int, rate_1 double precision, rate_2 double precision);

INSERT INTO my_table (id, type_key, rate_1, rate_2) 
VALUES
    (1, NULL, 0.2, 3),
    (2, 1, 1.3, 5),
    (3, 1, NULL, 10),
    (4, 2, 0.5, NULL),
    (5, 2, 0.01, 0),
    (6, 2, 0.75, NULL),
    (7, 3, NULL, NULL),
    (8, 3, 0.34, 1),
    (9, 3, NULL, 1);
```

And ideally, the resulting table would be:

```
(id, score_1, score_2)
    (1, NULL, NULL),
    (2, 0, 4),
    (3, NULL, 3),
    (4, 2, NULL),
    (5, 2, 4),
    (6, 3, NULL),
    (7, NULL, NULL),
    (8, 4, 2),
    (9, NULL, 3);
```

based on the scoring thresholds like so:

```
CASE WHEN type_key = 1 THEN (
            CASE
                WHEN rate_1 > .7 THEN 0
                WHEN rate_1 > .5 THEN 1
                WHEN rate_1 > .4 THEN 2
                WHEN rate_1 > .3 THEN 3
                ELSE 4
```

( and repeat for each type_key_n and rate_n )

ORIGINAL QUESTION:

I have a table, for simplicity, let's say it's got three columns: `date`, `name`, and `value`.

I want to create a table based off of this, where I've sorted each name into bins based on the magnitude of `value`.

Now, one way to do so would be to write:

```
CREATE TABLE resulting_table AS 
(SELECT DATE,
       name,
       CASE
         WHEN value >= magnitude_1 THEN result_1
         WHEN value >= magnitude_2 THEN result_2
         WHEN value >= magnitude_n THEN result_n
       END AS bins
FROM my_table)
```

but as n increases, this query gets very long and rather illegible. And if I have different threshold magnitudes for different `name`s, then I have to do a nested case statement like so:

```
CREATE TABLE resulting_table AS 
(SELECT DATE,
       CASE
         WHEN name = 'name_n' THEN
           CASE
             WHEN value >= name_n_magnitude_n THEN result_n_n
           END AS bins 
FROM my_table)
```

which means the query gets even longer and less legible.

I have two ideas for how to solve this, but I'm not quite sure which is better or how I would implement them.

1) Create a separate table for all `name`, `magnitude`, and `result` combinations. Join this table with `my_table` to get `resulting_table`

2) Use a blend of postgresql/psycopg2 and python to get this logic implemented in a way that's easy to read.

Any thoughts here? This seems like it would be a common data cleaning/data engineering issue.

Comment: It would be good to have a data example to test what you want to achieve. Your question is too ambiguous, it does not say much on what do you need besides making a query more legible. With an example of **input data** and **resulting data**, it would be better for anyone to help.

Comment: I'd say that having the various thresholds in a separate table with which you join sounds promising.

Comment: Can you use a better data model for `my_table`? as the real problem use many rate_x, use `CREATE TABLE my_table (id INT, type_key int, rate double precision[])` to populate values like `(1, NULL, array[0.2, 3]),
    (2, 1, [1.3, 5])`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Please a sample of your data, and more objectiveness about what you want, a "Python solution" or a "SQL solution". I prefer to solve most possible with SQL. Here a generic solution (see [Range Types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html)).

---

The good thing about SQL is also the ugly: it only runs perfectly with tabular data, there is no other data structure ... Even something similar to a matrix must be unnested. So your clue is correct: "create a separate table". But for small datasets there are some good options: array and JSONb. Lets use array of range types.

Starting with some didactic examples:

```
SELECT '[1,10)'::int4range @> 4, '[1,10)'::int4range @> 44; -- true, false
SELECT  idx, r @> 4 a,  r @> 44 b
FROM unnest(array[int4range(1,10),int4range(11,50)]) WITH ORDINALITY t(r,idx);
```

So, the array dataset is like a table, with its column type and primary key. Now you can match this array of ranges with any other array of values. The solution:

```
CREATE TABLE resulting_table AS 
(SELECT DATE,
       name,
       (SELECT (array['a','b','c'])[idx]  -- array of results
        FROM unnest(array[int4range(1,10),int4range(11,50),int4range(51,100)]) 
             WITH ORDINALITY t(magnitude,idx)
        WHERE magnitude @> value
       ) AS bins
FROM my_table)
```

This is faster tham use a table while little arrays (because is  compiled as "inline function"). Use [EXPLAN ANALYSE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/using-explain.html#USING-EXPLAIN-ANALYZE) when arrays need more tham ~1000 elements.

Answer (score 0):

answer for (second) edited question

### Assumptions and modeling

Supposing that  for each `type_key=n` exists a `rate_n`, and 
modeling your rates by array instead isolated values... So, supposing that `rate[type_key]` exist for all rows in your table.

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  id int,         -- same
  type_key int,   -- same
  rate double precision[] -- changed to array
);
INSERT INTO my_table 
    (id, type_key, rate) 
VALUES
    (1, NULL, array[0.2,  3, NULL]),
    (2, 1,    array[1.3,  5, NULL]),
    (3, 1,    array[NULL, 10, 0.2]),
    (4, 2,    array[0.5,  NULL,0.1]),
    (5, 2,    array[0.01, 0, 0.02]),
    (6, 2,    array[0.75, NULL,0.6]),
    (7, 3,    array[NULL::double precision, NULL,0.1]),
    (8, 3,    array[0.34, 1,0.31]),
    (9, 3,    array[NULL, 1,0.1])
;
```

### Complementing sample

Please better samples to test the solution... Example:

```
INSERT INTO my_table 
    (id, type_key, rate) 
VALUES
    (20, 1,    array[0.5, 0, 0]),
    (21, 1,    array[0.7, 0, 0]),
    (22, 2,    array[0, 0.7, 0])
;
```

### Solution

```
SELECT m.id, (
    SELECT COALESCE( max(idx)-1, 0 ) 
    FROM unnest(cmp[type_key:type_key]) WITH ORDINALITY tt(x,idx) 
    WHERE m.rate[type_key]>x
  ) score
FROM my_table m, 
     (select array[ 
       [0.0, 0.3,  0.4,  0.5,  0.7],  -- "case set" of rate_1
       [0.0, 0.31, 0.4,  0.45, 0.72], -- "case set" of rate_2
       [0.0, 0.22, 0.41, 0.55, 0.8]   -- "case set" of rate_3
      ]) t(cmp)
;
```

result

```
 id | score 
----+-------
  1 |     0
  2 |     4
  3 |     0
  4 |     0
  5 |     0
  6 |     0
  7 |     0
  8 |     1
  9 |     0
 20 |     2
 21 |     3
 22 |     3
```